# Spring kafka integration

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

I keep getting this compilation exception when I try to work with the following example: https://github.com/joshlong/spring-and-kafka

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getBytes(String) from the type String  DemoApplication.java    /spring-and-kafka-master/src/main/java/jc   line 120    Java Problem
>   The parameterized method valueEncoder(Encoder) of type KafkaProducerMessageHandlerSpec.ProducerMetadataSpec is not applicable for the arguments (String::getBytes)  DemoApplication.java    /spring-and-kafka-master/src/main/java/jc   line 120    Java Problem

Comment: An IDE issue? How about to build it with Maven or Gradle ?

Comment: built it with Maven. same pom.xml